# How to create an evernote notebook and notes in iOS evernote cloud api?

Tags: ios, ios5, evernote

I am trying to create a notebook from my app. The problem is I cannot create the notebook.

```
EDAMNotebook *notebook = [[EDAMNotebook alloc]init];
notebook.name = @" List";
EDAMNote *createdNote = [noteStore createNotebook:authToken :notebook];
```

Xcode tells me that noteStore does not exist. I tried importing NoteStore.h but that file does not exist.

So can someone please provide me with some code on how to create a notebook as well as a note in iOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`noteStore` is the name of an instance variable. If you haven't created and initialized it, then it does not exist.

What you probably want to do is call `[NoteStore createNotebook:authToken :notebook]`.  In the current version of the Evernote SDK, you would want to include `EvernoteNoteStore.h` and add the following line of code before `noteStore` is referenced:

```
EvernoteNoteStore *noteStore = [EvernoteNoteStore noteStore];
```

This will get the shared instance of the `EvernoteNoteStore` which you can use to create a new notebook.

Comment: Thanks. But I still cannot create a notebook. Here is what I have: 

EvernoteNoteStore *noteStore = [EvernoteNoteStore noteStore];
EDAMNotebook *notebook = [[EDAMNotebook alloc]init];
 EDAMNotebook *created = [noteStore createNotebook:notebook success:(EDAMNotebook *notebook)success failure:^(NSError *error)failure];// What do I put for success and faliure??

Comment: `success` and `failure` indicate blocks where code will run if the request succeeds or fails, respectively. Check [this file](https://github.com/evernote/simple-api-client-example-ios/blob/master/EvernoteCounter/ECViewController.m) starting at line 40 for something similar to what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

we cant create the notebook we can create only notes but not notebook

[I Posted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965882/hw-to-create-a-notebook-and-save-my-notes-in-that-notebook/16052123#16052123)