# How to create a notebook and save my notes in that notebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, evernote

1) I am saving some csv files in my evernote one by one order but i want all all files under one notebook  . At present i am saving notes under default notebook but i want createone notebook and then i want save my notes in that notebook

[image: i want like this]

2) At present i am converting that csv files into data so its showing some attached file after dowing its showing again csv files

But how to save file directly to evernote with out converting it to data?
     I am using following code

```
NSData *NewdataHash = [NewFileData md5];
    EDAMData *NewedamData = [[EDAMData alloc] initWithBodyHash:NewdataHash size:NewFileData.length body:NewFileData];
    EDAMResource* Newresource = [[EDAMResource alloc] initWithGuid:nil noteGuid:nil data:NewedamData mime:@"application/csv" width:0 height:0 duration:0 active:0 recognition:0 attributes:nil updateSequenceNum:0 alternateData:nil];
    NSString *NewnoteContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                                  "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">"
                                  "<en-note>"
                                  "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">CountDown DairiesList.</span>"
                                  "<br />"
                                  "<span>Evernote logo :</span>"
                                  "<br />"
                                  "%@"
                                  "</en-note>",[ENMLUtility mediaTagWithDataHash:NewdataHash mime:@"application/csv"]];

    NSMutableArray* Newresources = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[Newresource]];

    EDAMNote *NewnewNote = [[EDAMNote alloc] initWithGuid:nil title:@"DairiesList CSV" content:NewnoteContent contentHash:nil contentLength:NewnoteContent.length created:0 updated:0 deleted:0 active:YES updateSequenceNum:0 notebookGuid:nil tagGuids:nil resources:Newresources attributes:nil tagNames:nil];
    [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] createNote:NewnewNote success:^(EDAMNote *note)
     {   

       }  

      failure:^(NSError *error) {
 }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 EDAMNotebook* notebook = [[EDAMNotebook alloc] initWithGuid:nil name:eObj.title updateSequenceNum:0 defaultNotebook:NO serviceCreated:0 serviceUpdated:0 publishing:nil published:NO stack:nil sharedNotebookIds:nil sharedNotebooks:nil businessNotebook:nil contact:nil restrictions:nil]; 

[noteStore createNotebook:notebook success:^(EDAMNotebook *notebook)  
{
 NSData *NewdataHash = [NewFileData md5];
    EDAMData *NewedamData = [[EDAMData alloc] initWithBodyHash:NewdataHash size:NewFileData.length body:NewFileData];
    EDAMResource* Newresource = [[EDAMResource alloc] initWithGuid:nil noteGuid:nil data:NewedamData mime:@"application/csv" width:0 height:0 duration:0 active:0 recognition:0 attributes:nil updateSequenceNum:0 alternateData:nil];
    NSString *NewnoteContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                                  "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">"
                                  "<en-note>"
                                  "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">CountDown DairiesList.</span>"
                                  "<br />"
                                  "<span>Evernote logo :</span>"
                                  "<br />"
                                  "%@"
                                  "</en-note>",[ENMLUtility mediaTagWithDataHash:NewdataHash mime:@"application/csv"]];

    NSMutableArray* Newresources = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[Newresource]];
                                   EDAMNote *newNote = [[EDAMNote alloc] initWithGuid:notebook.guid title:titileString content:noteContent contentHash:nil contentLength:noteContent.length created:0 updated:0 deleted:0 active:YES updateSequenceNum:notebook.updateSequenceNum notebookGuid:notebook.guid tagGuids:nil resources:resources attributes:nil tagNames:nil];

                                  [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] createNote:newNote success:^(EDAMNote *note)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Note created successfully.");


                                   } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Error creating note : %@",error);
                                   }];


  }
                 failure:^(NSError *error)
                  {

                      NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
                   }];
```

Answer (score 1):

To save a note in a notebook, simply set the `notebookGuid` of the `EDAMNote` object that you create. You will need to convert to NSData to store the csv file.

Comment: in evernote its showing like one attached file after downloading i am getting same file but how can show like file in evernote?

Comment: At present i am writing that code 3 times for sending 3 different csv files so where i change that code? so that all these files under one name?

Comment: In the ENML, its up to you how you want to display it.

Comment: Can i have sample for posting like that?

Comment: please tell how to create a notebook?